# Mongoid::Config.purge! Not working with mongo 3

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

To clear the database between tests I've tried:

```
Mongoid::Config.purge!
```

and

```
Mongoid.purge!
```

Neither work, however if I do :

```
Mongoid.default_session.drop
```

between tests it works fine. Any ideas on how to get purge working?

I've seen behavior now on 3 computers (out of about 100 at work). I'm running mongoid 4.0.2, active model 4.0, and mongo 3.2.4